# Jquery Extend DialogBox is distorted in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jQuery Extend dialog box in my application it working fine in Chrome as well as IE but from the server has not working for IE

I have included the following libraries

```
<script src="/CLG/JavaScript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"  ></script>
<script src="/CLG/JavaScript/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"  ></script>
<link href="/CLG/Stylesheets/jquery/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/CLG/JavaScript/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/CLG/JavaScript/jquery.dialogextend.js"></script>
```

And Please find the below function from where dialog Box is opening

```
   function ShowNewDialogv1(URL, Style,width) {

    var hostname = document.domain;
    var dialogOptions = {
        "open": function () {
        },
        "close": function () {
        },
        "title": Style,
      //  "width": 400,
       // "height": 300,
        "modal": true,
        "resizable": false,
        "draggable": true
        //"close": function () { }
    };
    var dialogExtendOptions = {
        "closable": true,
        "maximizable": true,
        "minimizable": true,
        "collapsable": true
    };
    $(".ui - widget - header").css("width", "100");
    $("#NewPopupWindowv1 iframe").attr("src", "http://" + hostname + URL);
    $("#NewPopupWindowv1 iframe").css("height", "100%").css("border", "0px");
    $("#NewPopupWindowv1 iframe").css("width", "100%");

   $("#NewPopupWindowv1").dialog(dialogOptions).dialogExtend(dialogExtendOptions).dialog({
       // $("#NewPopupWindowv1").dialog(dialogOptions).dialog({
        dialogClass: "no-close",
        title: Style,
        height: 600,
        //appendTo: $("form:first"),
        width: parseInt(width),
        open: function () {      

            if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 8) {
                $(".ui-dialog").css("left", "25%").css("top", "10%").css("position", "absolute").css("overflow", "hidden").css("display", "block").css("height", "auto").css("width", "950px").css("z-index", "101");
                $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css("top", "30%");
                $(".ui-widget-header").css("width", "98%");
            }

            $("#NewPopupWindowv1 iframe").css("display", "block");
            $(".ui-widget-header").css("background", "#617D8D").css("color", "#ffffff");
            if (Style.indexOf("Demographic") > 0) {
                $("#NewPopupWindowv1 iframe").find("#RadPane1").css("display", "none");
            }

        },
        close: function () {                
            $("#NewPopupWindowv1 iframe").css("display", "none");
        },
        modal:true
    });
```

}